# Two double nested anonymous inner classes. How to get 1st level anonymous class members?

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

Inner class is Adapter, inner-inner class is Listener. How to access (obscured) Adapter members/methods from Listener?

```
list.setAdapter(new Adapter() {
  public View getView() {
    // ...
    button.setListener(new Listener() {
      public void onClick() {
        Adapter.this.remove(item);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Normally to access the outer classes members, you just say Outer.this.member, but in this case it gave me the following error (using the actual class):

```
error: not an enclosing class: ArrayAdapter
```

So how are you supposed to access an inner class members from an inner-inner class? I don't like multi-level nested anonymous classes, but in this case I'm learning a new API and am not sure of a cleaner way yet. I already have a workaround but wanted to know anyways. remove() isn't really obscured by the inner-inner class so specifying the class isn't really necessary in this case, but wanted to make it clear in the code exactly where this remove() method is. I also wanted to know in case it is obscured. I believe using `Outer.$6.remove()` would work, but I don't believe it should be that way either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assign `this` to a variable, then access that one of innermost class.

```
list.setAdapter(new Adapter() {
  public View getView() {
    final Adapter that = this;
    button.setListener(new Listener() {
      public void onClick() {
        that.remove(item);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what would be a good naming here. Perhaps `adapter`?

Comment: I see. I thought there would be a language syntax to use in order to get at Adapter that I didn't know about. BTW `that` would have to be final.

Comment: I prefer this approach as it is easily readable and explicit.

Comment: I get a compilation error on the line Adapter that = Adapter.this; (Adapter is not a enclosing class). Instead you should rather be saying final Adapter that=this.. if at all..

Answer (score 1):

Just call the method on Adapter directly:

```
list.setAdapter(new Adapter() {
  public View getView() {
    // ...
    button.setListener(new Listener() {
      public void onClick() {
        remove(item); // <-- this will call Adapter's method of the anonymous class
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I know that. But what if Listener has a remove() method. Then what?

Comment: Good question! I'll look into it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

its simple as this:  try outer.remove without this class pointer

Comment: That won't work. remove() is not a method of Outer. It is a method of Adapter.